# Command doesn't work after changing Children of parent element

Tags: c#, wpf, children, windowsformshost

I have to use `WindowsFormsHost` element for solving `overlay WebBrowser` problem!
But all command bindings are lost after I chaned `Children` property! Do you know how to rebind `Command Bindings` of element or how i can do not lose bindings ?

XAML

```
<StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel">
    <Button x:Name="CloseBtn" Command="{Binding Close}"  Width="56" IsEnabled="True" Content="close" Height="26" />
</StackPanel>
```

Code

```
public partial class Test : Window
{
    public Test()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel() { Close = new DelegateCommand(this.Close) };

        Loaded += (sender, args) => Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(AddContent));
    }

    private void AddContent()
    {
        this.FindName("CloseBtn");

        var btn = this.CloseBtn;
        //command will be worked if you uncomment following 2 lines
        //var cmd = btn.Command;
        //btn.Command = cmd;

        StackPanel.Children.RemoveAt(0);
        var wh = new WindowsFormsHost();
        var eh = new ElementHost();

        eh.Child = btn;
        wh.Child = eh;

        StackPanel.Children.Add(wh);
    }
}
```

My real problem more comlex and I have to find and resolve many bindings've been lost. But I need only good approach for that kind of problems!

Comment: Any error in the output window? What if you set the btn.DataContext to this.DataContext in the AddContent function?

Comment: @nkoniishvt There aren't any errors. But your suggestion is correct =) But how I've already noticed my real problem is more complex. So I have to do the same actions but for `Template` of my `Window`. And it's solution doesn't work there =( I have a `.xaml` style with a `grid`, and I'm trying wrap the first row into the `WindowsFormsHost` and after I call `rootGrid.Children.Remove(headerGrid);`my command bindings are lost!